# Проблемы с joomla

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, joomla

Я тут взял заказ на фрилансе, просто надо было подправить верстку, про cms не уточнил, узнал что сайт на joomla только когда заказчик выслал данные от админки и хостинга.
Это вообще 1 из первых моих заказов, так что опыта нету, и я даже просто не могу разобраться где тут сама верстка которую нужно подправить, вроде должна быть в publick_html и все в архиве 1.tolant.zip, но я все равно не догоняю.
Если кому не сложно объясните что и как тут)
Скрины с папок:
[image: скриншот с хостингна]
[image: из папки publick_html]
[image: И из архива 1.tolant]

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, разработку под Joomla в двух словах не объяснишь.
В Вашем случае, лично я вижу два варианта:

- или срочно читать документацию по Joomla ([тут](https://docs.joomla.org/Main_Page));
- или пока не поздно вернуть заказчику деньги (если взяли предоплату), извиниться и больше так не делать.